# Data structure for interpolating T along axis of numerical keys

Tags: c++, c++17

Is there a data structure that when initialized with a key1 at 10 and key2 at 20, when accessed at 15 will call an interpolation callback function with (key1, key2, 0.5) with return value T?

The callback ensures that we can use our preferred S-curve for the interpolation. I'm expecting accesses on each end to pass the same key in both with 1.0 as the factor.

Pseudo-code:

```
Container<float, MyStruct> container;
container.insert(10, MyStruct{  .x = 1.0f  });
container.insert(20, MyStruct{  .x = 2.0f  });

auto middlepoint = container.get(15,
    [] (const MyStruct& a, const MyStruct& b, float factor) {
        return MyStruct{ a.x * factor + b.x * (1.0 - factor) };
    });
assert(middlepoint.x ~ 1.5f);
```

Have you seen this? What is this data structure called?

Thanks

Comment: why close and repost the exact same question?

Comment: Because closing a question on a technicality shouldn't be validated? I'm just asking a question, friend

Comment: its not a technicality. The rule is quite clear: Aksing for external libraries = offtopic. If the old quesiton got closed why do you think this will be any different?

Comment: While I had no idea you couldn't ask about libraries, even the old question did ask for the name of a data structure. This time I made sure to not break the rule, so hopefully I am good on that end.

Comment: funfact: your old question had 2 upvotes, this one doesnt. You dont need to delete a question just because it is closed, you could have tried to fix the old one so it could have been reopened

Comment: Right. When the old question was closed there was a dialogue where I could edit the question (I tried that but it remained closed) or delete it. In the end I deleted it, but I'll take your advice.

Comment: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), not trying to be snarky, but it seems like you missed that before

Comment: Pretty sure such a datastructure is not part of the standard library, probably you have to write one yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not just a data structure you are looking for, but a way to retrieve information from it. You can use a map + find_if:

```
#include <map>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

template <typename C,typename I>
double get(const C& container,double x,I interp) {
    auto it = std::find_if(container.begin(),container.end(),[x](auto e){ return e.first > x;});
    return interp(std::prev(it)->second,it->second);
}

int main() {
    std::map<double,double> m{ {1,0.0},{2,3.0},{3,5.0}};
    std::cout << get(m,1.5,[](auto x1,auto x2){ return 0.5*(x1 + x2);});
}
```

Prints: 1.5

Maybe 2-3 more lines are needed to handle edge cases, but otherwise above is all you need. Sometimes a wheel is really just a wheel and can be crafted by building on existing containers and algorithms. I don't expect to find this anywhere as a container, but rather as a interpolation function along the line of `interpolate(some_array_with_x_values,some_array_with_y_values,x)`.

Comment: If you're doing linear search, wouldn't it be better use `std::vector<std::pair<double, doulbe>>`?

Comment: I'm wondering if the std::prev on it is undefined behavior when it == begin

Comment: @GuillaumeRacicot not sure, depends on whether insertions are needed frequently, if not then definitely a sorted vector + binary search

Comment: @gonzo yes it is, as I wrote, a bit more is needed to handle edge cases. As I am not actually answering your question directly I didnt pay too much attention to details, but just wanted to show that it can be done without too much effort